props are not defined
I populate data from App.js to CarDetails page.
App.js
  const [data, setData] = useState<CarType[]>([])
   <Route exact path="/carDetails/:id">
      <CarDetails data={data} />
   </Route>

Once I get data prop in DetailsPage, it's also defined but method find() does not find any of the items filtered through the data prop. const found is undefined. meanwhile data prop is an array of objects and it's defined.
CarDetails.js
const CarDetails = (data=[]) => 
const [item, setItem] = useState<CarType>({} as CarType)

  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
  useEffect(() => {
    const found = data.find((item) => item.id === id)
    if (found) {
      setItem(found)
    }
  console.log(data, 'data', found, 'found')
  
  }, [data, id])

Here is the output of the console: (data and found)



According to the docs .find() will return undefined if nothing is found. Therefore check your values to debug this. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

item.id is a number type, route params are strings, they will never be strictly equal.
